# What could cause the camera to turn on automatically while the phone is in standby?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, camera, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I have a Samsung Galaxy S5 (the blue one just to help set the scene) running Android version 4.4.2

My phone was sleeping beside me peacefully on my desk in standby mode (or whatever you call it when it's just a blank screen not being used).

Suddenly, the screen lights up and to my surprise the camera is active - with no human intervention whatsoever. There were also no notifications of any kind at this point that might have had a hand in it.

What could be the possible causes for this to happen? Are there any conditions is which this might be expected? Is it a bug? Or maybe worse, could it be a malicious application trying to "catch me in the act"?

**Additional information that might be useful:**

- When the camera started it was the main camera that was active, rather than the front camera
- Looking through the phone and camera settings, there is nothing enabled (or even available) that might explain this happening. For example, there is no quick start camera gesture or voice command

Comment: Maybe you have a broken camera button? Did your phone every have a bad fall?

Comment: @geffchang: Nope, I have been very careful with this one and I have only had it just over a month. There doesn't appear to be a hardware shortcut for the camera anyway. There is a lockscreen software shortcut that requires you to slide an icon, but there was no contact with the phone at the time to manage this (of course there may be a bug that *thought* is was activated)

Comment: When you say "the camera is active", do you mean the camera app is visible on screen? A malicious app wouldn't use the camera app, it would just take pictures with nothing on screen.

Comment: Could this be the photo unlock?

Comment: The NSA. Just had to poke that one :-) Seriously,  though, maybe the OS has a gesture that turns on the camera automatically, and the detection's off. May be worth a trip through the settings to confirm.

Comment: @DanHulme: Yeah good point. It was active on the screen

Comment: @ctt: Just been through the settings and can't find anything that actives anything, let alone the camera

Comment: @JCHulce: Not sure what you mean by "the photo unlock"...

Comment: @musefan the face unlock feature, which was introduced in Android 4.0, allows you to unlock a device using facial recognition with the front camera. Details here: http://www.android.com/about/ice-cream-sandwich/ (near the bottom)

Comment: @JCHulce: Oh *face* unlock. That is not enabled on my phone, and I wouldn't expect it to activate the phone automatically. It also was the main camera being viewed, rather than the front camera

Comment: @musefan great to clarify this. You might want to edit the question a bit to say the main camera was activated.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly a solution, but [this](http://phandroid.com/2014/04/30/50-samsung-galaxy-s5-tips-tricks/) seems to be part of the problem:

> Launch Camera directly from lock screen
>
> Time is often of the essence when trying to capture the perfect
>   picture. The Galaxy S5 lets you bypass the lock screen to snap a
>   picture. Simply swipe the camera icon up (in the lower right hand
>   corner) and you’ll launch directly into the camera app! If this
>   feature isn’t turned on you can do so by:
>
> Go to Settings > Lock Screen Check “Camera Shortcut” You’re done! Even
>   if you have a pattern or password lock set up this will let you take
>   pictures without unlocking your phone.

How this is being enabled is anyones guess.

Comment: Yeah I did think this could be the most likely cause, somehow it thought that it had been triggered. If it is this, then it definitely a bug, I guess it's hard to know for sure what the cause was

Comment: Faulty touchscreen? Perhaps it is detecting phantom touches where the camera app icon is on the lockscreen?

Comment: No reason to suspects faulty touchscreen, I haven't noticed any issues with it. Also, the camera unlock doesn't work unless the lock screen is visible. If I try and to the unlock while the screen is black then it doesn't work, so even with physical screen interaction it doesn't unlock, which I believe rules out the phone thinking it's being touched. But still leaves the potential for the camera unlock widget to falsely assume it has been activated.

Comment: Well to activate the camera, the phone has to wake up, then the lock icon has to be tapped. Could these actions be the result of faulty hardware? It would require 2 coincidences - wake up action (either software (possible caused by an app) or hardware related) and then the camera app is activated too. Seems a long shot.

Comment: Since the phone is relatively new, perhaps its best to try a  hardware reset now (as opposed to 6 months later, when you have lots of data on it). Then try it for a few days without installing too many apps off the market. If it does this weird behaviour in its factory reset state, then send it back to samsung and get a replacement.

Answer (score 1):

I have an s6 and my phone got sprayed with a little (just a little)  water and later the camera and google app were launching randomly on their own. Both the camera and the google app have shortcut launch options via the home button. It went on for about fifteen minutes before stopping. My guess is a drop or so went in and activated the button sensors. It's still popping up randomly as I type. Turning off the quick launch for the camera made sure that it's only the google app that's launching itself now.

Comment: Your home button still worked when you pressed it to go to the home-screen? You didn't specifically mention it.

Comment: It was a long time ago now, and the problem didn't stay around too long. At this point I am putting it down to a bug in the OS that was quickly patched

Comment: I've got the same happening after use in water. The camera randomly turns on both from lock screen with the phone on the table and when in use.

Comment: For me disabling the power button double click gesture didn't work, but in the camera settings there was another setting for the Sony Xperia camera button and disabling that resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

could it be  an app that you downloaded and gave permission to use camera, along with other things on phone, we have to give up alot of privacy when we hit the accept button with out paying attention to what they want to have access to